Flutter app does not debugged afer dowload github
I had published my app to the AppStore and after that I bought a new macbook. And I downloaded project from github and tried to debug. But now an error occured and I'd never faced an issue like that:
My project is developed with Flutter and my flutter and other setups don't have any issue.
If you help, appricate that.
ProcessException: Process exited abnormally with exit code 1:
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=IXUserPresentableErrorDomain, code=1):
App installation failed: Unable to Install “Uscan”
Please try again later.
Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path
/Users/umitkar/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6DF53204-2EE0-4E2C-AAE2-144ECAA4FE8D/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.bwXW2T/extracted/Runner.app/Frameworks/A
pp.framework; Extra info about
"/Users/umitkar/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6DF53204-2EE0-4E2C-AAE2-144ECAA4FE8D/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.bwXW2T/extracted/Runner.app/Frameworks/
App.framework/Info.plist": dev=16777230 ino=6517025 mode=0100644 nlink=1 uid=501 gid=20 rdev=0 size=300 atime=1733260998.631274 mtime=1733175480.000000 ctime=1733260998.622615
birthtime=1733175480.000000 blksize=4096 blocks=8 flags=0x0 firstBytes={length = 4, bytes = 0x3c3f786d} ACL=<not found> extendedAttributes={
    "com.apple.provenance" = {length = 11, bytes = 0x0102000a9130a7e079331c};
} keyCount=1 keySample={ flutter.assets } 
Underlying error (domain=IXUserPresentableErrorDomain, code=1):
        Unable to Install “Uscan”
        Please try again later.
  Command: /usr/bin/arch -arm64e xcrun simctl install 6DF53204-2EE0-4E2C-AAE2-144ECAA4FE8D /Users/umitkar/dev/flutter/uscan/build/ios/iphonesimulator/Runner.app```


did you  run following commands for your app before run like.
flutter clean , flutter pub get, cd ios, pod install
